# How use IF to classify one variable in irregular intervals

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a data frame call DATA, i need to classify in irregular intervals the variable X, in something like this:

```
yy   mm     A     Class
1958   1    0.44   Neutro
1958   2    0.41   Neutro
1958   3    0.60   Calida debil
1958   4    0.55   Calida debil
1958   5    0.40   Neutro
1958   6    0.26   Neutro
1958   7    0.03   Neutro
1958   8    2.5    Calida Fuerte
1958   9    3.5    Calida Extraordinario
```

I think in this but it dont work well

```
X <- DATA$A
Class <- character(length(X))
for (i in 1:length(X))
if ( X[i] < -1.4) {
    Class[i] <- "Fría Fuerte"
} else if (X[i] >= -1.4 | X[i] < -1.2 ) {
    Class[i] <- "Fría Moderada"
} else if (X[i] >= -1.2 | X[i] < -1.0 ) {
    Class[i] <- "Fría Débil"
} else if (X[i] >= -1.0 | X[i] <= 0.4 ) {
    Class[i] <- "Neutro"
} else if (X[i] > 0.4 | X[i] <= 1.0 ) {
    Class[i] <- "Cálida Débil"
} else if (X[i] > 1.0 | X[i] <= 1.7 ) {
    Class[i] <- "Cálida Moderada"
} else if (X[i] > 1.7 | X[i] <= 3.0 ) {
    Class[i] <- "Cálida Fuerte"
} else (X[i] > 3.0)
    Class[i] <- "Cálida Extraordinaria"
```

Thanks

Comment: How is `1 <= x < 0.44` possible? Do you mean `0.1 <= x < 0.44`?

Comment: You may want to look at `cut` function.

Comment: for-loop definitely not needed for this. What's I_ICEN[i] by the way?

Comment: Something along these lines should work for you: `df$newx <- cut(df$X, breaks = c(-Inf, 0.1, 0.44, 0.6), labels = c('A', 'B', 'C'))`

Comment: I just edit the question, my english is not good